# Performing Regression using group by

Tags: r, data.table

I want to build a regression model by grouping a  categorical variable(Item_ID)

I tried doing the following, however i am getting the following error:

```
a <- train[,predict(lm(Number_Of_Sales ~ Year + Month + Day + Weekday + day_of_year  + Category_3  + Category_2  + Category_1 + Weeknum), test[.BY]), by = Item_ID]

b <- test[,predict(lm(Number_Of_Sales ~ Year + Month + Day + Weekday + day_of_year  + Category_3  + Category_2  + Category_1 + Weeknum, data = train[.BY]), newdata=.SD),by = Item_ID]
```

> ```
> Error in `[.data.frame`(test, , predict(lm(Number_Of_Sales ~ Year + Month +  : 
>   unused argument (by = Item_ID)
> ```

`Item_ID` is present in both test and train datasets. I tried using `train$Item_ID`, but that was also not working. Could you please help on this?

***** Updated question to reproduce the error ****

```
train <- data.frame(state=rep(c('MA', 'NY'), c(10, 10)),
                year=rep(1:10, 2),
                response=c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10)))


test <- data.frame(state=rep(c('MA', 'NY'), c(5, 5)),
                    year=rep(1:5, 2),
                    response=c(rnorm(5), rnorm(5)))


a <- train[,predict(lm(response ~ Year), test[.BY]), by = state]
```

Error received:

> ```
> Error in `[.data.frame`(train, , predict(lm(response ~ Year), test[.BY]),  : 
>   unused argument (by = state)
> ```

Comment: AFAIK, `by` inside `[` is a data.table feature, see whether the linked post solves your problem.

Comment: somehow i am not able to identify the problem.

Comment: Including a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) would make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Jaap - Thank you. Included a reproducable example

Comment: You are using `data.table` syntax on a dataframe. Convert your dataframes to datatables with `setDT()` first.

Comment: @Jaap - You are right. This has worked. Thanks a lot.